Philosophy behind the Ricci flow
I don't know if my question is too simple for this forum but let me proceed.
In Ricci flow one equips a smooth manifold $M$ with a Riemannian metric $g_0$ and evolves the metric with "time": giving rise to $g_t$. Then one interprets the singularities, formed in finite time, in $g_t$ as indicating that $M$ has to be changed (via surgery) to prolong the evolution.
If I think of $M$ as a surface and embedded in Euclidean 3-space, and I think of the metric as giving it a shape (maybe as the pullback of the flat metric), then I can be convinced that a singularity in the metric makes the surface singular in the sense that it may pinch off somewhere or completely shrink to a point.
But I don't understand how this should follow from the definitions of $M$ as a smooth manifold. In other words I am asking: why do we interpret singularities in the metric as singularities in the underlying manifold? After all, we can specify $M$ without any reference to a metric.

You shouldn’t think of this as something happening to a smooth manifold, but to a manifold equipped with a Riemannian metric.  Here’s a much easier example.  Imagine a surface with a metric.  Deform the metric by pinching a loop to a point.  At the end of this process, you have something that is not a Riemannian metric since vectors tangent to the loop now have length $0$.  It’s natural to now quotient this loop to a point (ie identify points that have “distance” 0) to get a surface with a nodal singularity since the non-metric on the surface induces an actual metric on the singular space.

@AndyPutman So in a sense, you're considering the metric topology derived from $g$; and this happens to coincide with the topology of $M$ unless $g$ is singular in which case the two topologies are different?

You don't just change the topology on $M$, you change the underlying set by quotienting to identify points that are distance $0$ from each other.  What you get can be pretty complicated, which is why it is so important to classify the singular metrics that occur.  That's where all the hard work in this business is.

The Ricci flow behaves like a heat equation for the curvature with some additional reaction terms. Intuitively, the diffusion term acts to spread the curvature out and make the geometry more homogeneous. The catch is that the reaction terms tend to make the curvature more positive, so the curvature can concentrate until the space becomes singular.
So it is natural to ask why singularities must emerge. Some of them are fairly natural, such as what happens when a sphere shrinks to a point. In this case, the curvature is growing without bound but spreads evenly through so the limiting spaces are round (though very small). And for surfaces, this is the only way a singularity can emerge. If one starts with a surface of genus one or more, the limiting metric is either flat or hyperbolic (after rescaling), so the Ricci flow converges to the canonical metric on the surface.
But three-dimensional manifolds don’t always admit metrics of constant curvature. However, they can be decomposed into multiple pieces which admit one of eight canonical geometries. Very roughly speaking, the singularities of Ricci flow in three dimensions occur in ways to make this structure more apparent. (Technically speaking, the surgeries process on a 3-fold does not give its Geometrization, but it does break it into pieces where the decomposition can be understood, which is how Perelman proved the Geometrization conjecture.)
In higher dimensions, the singularities can be even more complicated, and there isn’t a simple interpretation for them in general. However, in many cases they are detecting regions where the surgery must occur to find a canonical geometry.
Here are some additional points which might help clarify things:

Interpreting the Ricci flow as a heat-type equation is a bit subtle because of a property known as diffeomorphism invariance. However, there’s an argument by Deturck which addresses this issue.
Ricci flow only makes sense for a Riemannian manifold, and it’s helpful to not think about it as being embedded in some higher dimensional Euclidean space but rather just existing as an intrinsic geometric space.
As a simple model for how singularities to Ricci flow can emerge, it is helpful to consider the non-linear reaction-diffusion equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u = \Delta u + u^2$, which behaves quite similarly.


Thank you for your interest in the question. You said that the kind of singularities that occur may be complicated. But now I'm very interested to know the extent to which surgery can fix a singularity (in the sense that, after surgery, the flow can continue). So concretely: is p-surgery (where one cuts out some $S^p\times B^{d-p}$ and glues in $B^{p+1}\times S^{d-p-1}$ along the common boundary), for any $p$, always guaranteed to fix a singularity, however complicated?

I’m not sure of all the possible structures for singularities. Part of Perelman’s work was classifying three-dimensional gradient solitons which arise as singularity models, but I believe there are still several open questions about this.

In general, the singularities will not just be handle constructions. For instance, in the analytic minimal model program one attempts to use Kahler-Ricci flow to find a minimal model in birational geometry. In that case, I believe the singularities often occur along curves that should be blown up. However, this is not my area of expertise so someone else might be able to fill in more details on this.
